# I want to generate a list of 10 distinct random 2-digit integer numbers

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a list of 10 distinct random 2-digit integer numbers. And find the values cubes

```
import random as r
import math as i

ss = [r.randint(10,100) for i in range(10)]
print(i.pow(ss))
```

I did it wrong so i need some help.

Comment: `ss = [r.randint(10,99) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: If you look at the documentation of `randint()` you'll see that it will generate a value the range of values you pass it, so from `range(10, 100)` in this case. You need to do something extra to have it generate 10 of them.

Comment: @GhostOps Those won't necessarily be distinct.

Comment: @AmiTavory yes of course i know, thats why i upvoted your answer

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your question lacks the expected and actual output. Also, why you think you "did it wrong" would be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.sample`

```
import random

random.sample(range(10, 100), 10))
```

> sample() is an inbuilt function of random module in Python that returns a particular length list of items chosen from the sequence i.e. list, tuple, string or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It's very naive, and could probably be done in a more clever way, but:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < 10:
    n = random.randint(10, 100)
    if not n in numbers:
        numbers.append(n)
```

We're going to loop as long as we haven't generated ten numbers. Each time we generate a random 2 digit number and if it's not already in `numbers`, append it to that list.

When we're done, `numbers` will contain ten *distinct* random two digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

random.sample is the best way to do this especially because it checks that the sample and population make sense.

However, if you can **guarantee** that that's never going to be a problem, you could use a set as follows:

```
import random

NVALS = 10
R_LO = 10
R_HI = 100

result = set()

while len(result) < NVALS:
    result.add(random.randint(R_LO, R_HI))

print(result)
```